# MVC 6 Create View issues : There was an error creating the DBContext to get the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Attempting to create a view for "Create" using the NavBar Model and the NavBarEntity shown below (in MVC6) receives this message...

[image]

*There was an error running the selected code generator: There was an error creating the DBVContext instance to get the model...  Value cannot be null...  Parameter Name: connectionString*

I picked this mode in View Wizard...

```
public class NavBarModel
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public List<LinkModel> Links { get; set; }
}
```

This DBContext class is shown here...

```
public class NavBarEntity : DbContext
    {
        public NavBarEntity()
        {
            ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        [Key]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public DbSet<List<LinkModel>> Links { get; set; }
    }
```

And the LinkModel shown here..

```
public class LinkModel
{
    public LinkModel()
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
    [Key]
    private string ID { get; set; }
    public string HREF { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Configure Services looks like this...

```
        var cfg2 = Configuration["Data Source=MyPC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Dashboard;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"];
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(cfg))
            .AddDbContext<NavBarEntity>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(cfg2);
            });
```

Question: What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help listed above..

For newbies to MVC6 and EF7, the method named ConfigureServices, must contain a json pointer to the appsetting.json.  That method is found in the Startup.cs file.

This is the services configuration to match the code shown above. The string value in the brackets points to the json location...

```
        var cfg2 = Configuration["Data:DashboardContext:ConnectionString"];
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<DashboardContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(cfg2);
            })
```

But, you must also put a value into appsettings.json like this:

```
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet5-TestWebApplication1-d91c23e4-3565-476d-a7c0-45665bc0c367;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    },
    "DashboardContext": {
       "ConnectionString": "Data Source= MYPC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Dashboard;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
      }
  },
```

The **root cause** of the *Parameter Name: connectionString* being null was that the appsettings.json has to be exactly as shown above.  The json parsing routines must be able to locate the string name/value pair... Notice that these configurations fall under the "Data" name that contains other names.  in this case "DefaultConnection" was there by default, and I added "DashboardContext" portion.

Also in MVC 6 you must change the connectionString type to IServiceProvider and NOT string as was done before...

```
public class DashboardContext : DbContext
{
    public DashboardContext(IServiceProvider connectionString) : base (connectionString)
    {}
  public DbSet<NavBarEntity> NavBars { get; set; }
}
```

Alas: The Views created no problem...Yes!

[image: The Views]

Comment: The string in the constructor applies to EF6, which I had assumed is what you were using (I misread MVC6 as EF6 :-) I've added the EF7 version to my answer for completeness. The other bits about the entity not inheriting from the DbContext still applies although this obviously wasn't the root cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've tried to combine the DbContext and your entity isn't right. The DbContext should reference any entities you have as DbSets - entities should not inherit from it.

Your DbContext should look similar to this (EF6)

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
   public MyDbContext(string connectionString) 
      : base(connectionString)
   { }

   public DbSet<NavBarEntity> NavBars { get; set; }
   // Other entities
}
```

The constructor takes the name of the connecting string entry that's defined in your web.config you want to use. There are other ways to do this though - see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj592674.aspx)

Then create your entities as a simple class (POCO):

```
public class NavBarEntity
{
   public NavBarEntity()
   {
      ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   }

   [Key]
   public string ID { get; set; }

   // Other properties/columns here
}
```

**EDIT**

My original answer was based on EF6 rather than EF7. Here's how I would implement the context in EF7 for completeness:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
   public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) 
      : base(options)
   { }

   public DbSet<NavBarEntity> NavBars { get; set; }
   // Other entities
}
```